# Mouse Position weirdness

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

I have been having issues with referencing where the mouse is in a Windows Game (XNA Framework) recently. I create a variable:

```
Mouse mouse = Mouse.GetState();
```

and then attempt to get where the mouse's x and y coordinates are. And for a while it is fine, giving me the correct coordinates. But there has always been some breaking point where, after reached, the mouse returns and x and y greater than that of the mouse's actual coordinates. This is the fourth time this has happened and I have changed anything else that should interfere with it. Any ideas?

Comment: It is difficult to say as it is; my Mouse.GetState() behaves perfectly fine. Can you please provide your code?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using some kind of camera? If that's the case be sure to subtract camera position from
mouse position. Mouse.GetState().Position represents mouse position inside your window not your gameworld.